# create a new directory for every new state in the list of tuples in python

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples

Below is the list of tuples i have

**[('Abbeville', 'Alabama'), ('Abernant', 'Alabama'), ('PortLions', 'Alaska'), ('PrudhoeBay', 'Alaska')]**

From the above list of tuples i want to create a new directory for every new state.**i.e(for Alabama and Alaska)**

Please help me out guys
Thanks in advance

Comment: @jimidime- different folders for Alabama and Alaska

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create directory for each state

```
import os
places = [('Abbeville', 'Alabama'), ('Abernant', 'Alabama'), ('PortLions', 'Alaska'), ('PrudhoeBay', 'Alaska')]

for city, state in places:
    directory = '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/' + state
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)
```

Comment: when i try to create the directory at a particular location its giving error **OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/Desktop/Alabama'**

Comment: can you put your code snippet in the question? Its working for me.

Comment: i just tried adding the path to the line **os.mkdir(state)** -- and it throws an error after adding this  **os.mkdir('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/' + state)**